# How to validate a drop down box option before allowing the user to be sent to the next page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, error-handling

**Reasoning:**

I am in the final stages of my report error form however I have hit a wall on something that I thought we be easily solved.

The problem is that employees who send the reports are lazy and don't select their name and leave the one name that is there already in place and submit the error with another employees name in the report. Problem with this is that if we need to chase up the employee for further questioning we may be sent to someone who didn't send it all due to pure laziness.

Many of the tutorials that I have looked at don't seem to work with what i am trying to achieve so I came here to try get an answer.

**Description:**

We made a blank option however employees would just leave it blank so now we are making it so that the employee must select a name and if they don't they will be greeted with a message saying that they must choose a name before sending the report similar to many forms on other sites that require a name, email, birth date etc.

This is the bit of the form that needs the error checking:

```
        <tr>
           <td>Name:</td> 
           <td>
           <select name="users">
           <option value=""></option> //catch error if this option is chosen.
           <?php
           foreach($users as $key => $value){
           echo "<option value=\"$key\">$key</option>";
           }
           ?>
           </select>
           </td>
        </tr>
```

As you can see it uses a dynamic list and gets all the users that are clocked in at the moment to show up in the list. I know how to chuck up an error message when the option is left blank however when the employee submits it blank it sends the report to the specified emails and APIs and directs the user to the "Thanks for reporting issue page" without requiring the users to input a valid option no matter what. How would I fix this?

**TLDR Question:**

How do I make it so that an error is thrown and stops the user from continuing an sending the report?

Here is my full code for further reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main_style.css">
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid white;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<script>
function close_window() {
    close();
}
</script>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include("includes/classes.php");
include("includes/classes_monitoring.php"); 
$link = open_v8_db();
$users = get_clocked_in_users();
$OperationID = @$_REQUEST['OperationID'];

$title = "";
$grayedOut = false;
$disabledInput = "";
$hiddenJobDiv = "";
$hiddenPartDiv = "";
$ID = "";
$html = "";

$jobid    = @$_REQUEST['JobID'];
$part_id  = @$_REQUEST['PartID'];
$machCode = @$_REQUEST['Machine'];

if ($OperationID == 20)
{   
    $title = "Punching Machine";
    $grayedOut = true;
}
elseif ($OperationID == 30)
{
    $title = "Folding Machine";
    $grayedOut = true;
}
elseif ($OperationID == 40 || $OperationID == 140)
{
    $title = "Powder Coating";
    $grayedOut = true;
}
elseif ($OperationID == 50 || $OperationID == 150)
{
    $title = "Assembly";
    $grayedOut = true;
}
elseif ($OperationID == 60 || $OperationID == 160)
{
    $title = "Inspection";
    $grayedOut = true;
}
elseif ($jobid != "" && $part_id == "")
{
    $title = "Job";
    $OperationID = 70;
}
else
{
    $title = "General";
    $OperationID = 80;
    $grayedOut = false;
}

if ($greyedOut = true)
{
    $disabledInput = "readonly";
}

function customErr($ID)
{
    $html = "";
    $issueReport_folder = 'document/Production System/';
    $issueReporting = $issueReport_folder.'IssueReporting.csv';
    $file_handle = fopen($issueReporting, "r");

    if ($ID == 20)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[2] == "Punch")
            {
                $html[] = $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($ID == 30)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[2] == "Fold")
            {
                $html[] = $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($ID == 40 || $ID == 140)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[2] == "Powder")
            {
                $html[] = $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($ID == 50 || $ID == 150)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[2] == "Assembly")
            {
                $html[] = $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($ID == 60 || $ID == 160)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[2] == "Inspectoin")
            {
                $html[] = $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($ID == 70)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[2] == "Job")
            {
                $html[] = $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($ID == 80)
    {
        while (!feof($file_handle))
        {
            $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
            if ($line_of_text[2] == "General")
            {
                $html[] = $line_of_text[1];
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $html;
}

$jobErr = $partErr = $machErr = "";
$job = $part = $mach = $note = "";

if ($jobid == "")
{
    $hiddenJobDiv = "style=\"display:none;";
}
if ($part_id == "")
{
    $hiddenPartDiv = "style=\"display:none;";   
}

function test_input($data) 
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
<div class="reportForm">                                                                                                                
    <h2>Report <u><?php echo $title; ?></u> Error</h2>
    <form action="send_form_email.php?OperationID=<?php print ($OperationID) ?>&title=<?php print ($title) ?>" method="post"> 
        <table>
        <tr>
           <td>Name:</td> 
           <td>
           <select name="users">
           <option value=""></option>
           <?php
           foreach($users as $key => $value){
           echo "<option value=\"$key\">$key</option>";
           }
           ?>
           </select>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td <?php print $hiddenJobDiv ?>>Job Number:</td> 
           <td><input type="text" name="jobid" value="<?php echo ($jobid) ?>" <?php echo $disabledInput ?>></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td <?php print $hiddenPartDiv ?>>Part Number:</td> 
           <td><input type="text" name="partid" value="<?php echo ($part_id) ?>" <?php echo $disabledInput ?>></td>
        </tr>
           <?php if ($OperationID == 20){ ?>
             <tr>
               <td>Machine:</td> 
               <td><input type="text" name="mach" value="<?php echo ($machCode) ?>" <?php echo $disabledInput ?>></td>
             <tr>
           <?php } ?>
        </table><br>
        Error:<br><br><br>                                                                                                                                        <!-- Display of dynamic list. -->
        <?php
        $html = customErr($OperationID);                                                                                                                          
        foreach ($html as $oneError):?>                                                                                                                           <!-- foreach used to find the next iteration of the array. -->
        <label>                                                                                                                                                   <!-- Beginning of the dynamic radio button list. -->
            <input name="category"                                                                                                                                
            type="radio"
            value="<?php echo $oneError; ?>">                                                                                                                     <!-- Dynamic value to be used in Slack API and email. -->
            <?php echo $oneError; ?>                                                                                                                              <!-- Dynamic value as a visual representation for user. -->
        </label><br><br><br>
        <?endforeach;?>                                                                                                                                           <!-- Stops foreach and goes to next object if avaliable. -->
        <label>                                                                                                                                                   <!-- A permanent radio button labeled "Other" for (cont.) -->
        <input name="category" type="radio" value="Other" checked>Other                                                                                           <!-- all report error forms. -->
        </label><br><br><br>
        Note:<br> <textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="70" placeholder="More detail... (Is there a way to recreate the error? What happened?)"></textarea>    <!-- Allows the user to type in a custom message/note. -->
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="userFriendly">                                                                                   <!-- A large 'submit' button for touch screen. -->
        <a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;"><input type="submit" name="close" value="Close" class="userFriendly"></a>                              <!-- A large 'close' button for touch screens. -->
    </form>                                                                                                                                                       <!-- End of form. -->
</div>                                                                                                                                                            
</body>                                                                                                                                                           
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " I know how to chuck up an error message when the option is left blank however when the employee submits it blank"... if you can do that you are 99% there.

Seems like you just need to cancel the form submit at that point.

Comment: @BizzyBob exactly! rcpinto has got it so that it doesn't submit is a null value. Just gotta get it so it prints an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a *onsubmit* event to your form which returns false if "users" is empty and true otherwise.

```
<form ... onsubmit="return this.users.value != ''">
```

You may want to add an alert before the return too.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Give one option value as 'default' and do the validation while clicking the submit button, check whether that value equals to 'default' and then alert the user 'Plz enter the valid user name'.

**Option 2:**

If you have login system, automatically get user from session variable and put it on the select value and then disabled it.

Comment: Have already tried option 1, doesn't work. No login system as it gets data from M1 database, so option 2 doesn't work. ty for answer though.

Comment: I have written the click and ajax call . Check the function $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
  $selectedValue = $('select.users option:selected').text();

  if($selectedValue == '') {
    alert('Enter something');
  }
  else {
    //do the ajax call and send whatever the data
    $.ajax({
      url: 'send_form_email.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data : data,
      success: function(data){
        
      },
      error: function(data){
        
      }
    });
  }
});

Comment: I have never really used ajax except some alerts. Able too give me anymore information on what or how this would be implemented?

Comment: I have already written the function for you. whatever the data that u need to send, pass in the data like data: { jobId: $('input[name=jobid]').val(), partId: $('input[name=partid]').val() },    and grab in php For reference, see ajax jQuery documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple html required option if user didn't select it will show error message

Comment: You learn something new everyday. Did not know such a thing existed. Thanks.